# Why is the module not callable

Tags: python, class, python-3.x, module

I have most of my program done however I keep getting the error and can't seem to figure out why it keeps doing so.  I've also tried `animal_list = Zoo.Zoo()`

```
line 43, in addAnimal
    animal_list = Zoo()
TypeError: 'module' object is not callable
```

here is some of my program

```
import Animal
import Zoo
def main():
    #set user choice 
    choice = 0
    while choice != "3":
        display_menu()

        #get user's choice
        choice = str(input("What would you like to do? "))

        #Perform selected choice
        if choice.isalpha():
            print("Please enter a numeical value")

        elif choice == "1":
            addAnimal()
```

and

```
#Add animal to list
def addAnimal():
    atype = input("What type of animal would you like to create? ")
    aname = input("What is the animal's name? ")
    theAnimal = Animal.Animal(atype, aname)
    theAnimal.set_animal_type(atype)
    theAnimal.set_name(aname)
    animal_list = Zoo()
    animal_list.add_animal(theAnimal,Animal)
```

Comment: What is in the `Zoo` module?  Is there a class called `Zoo` in there?

Comment: @Trevor, please provide what is definition of `Zoo` ?

Comment: I will assume that you have stored your animal in zoo file, so call 'from zoo import animal'.

Answer (score 2):

From *looking at your other questions*, your `Zoo` class is quite wrong.

Your `Zoo` class ***should*** be written like this:

```
class Zoo:

    def __init__(self):
        self.__animals = []

    def add_animal(self, animals):
        self.__animals.append(animal)

    def show_animals(self):
        size = len(self.__animals)
        if size == 0:
            print("There are no animals in your zoo!")
        else:
            return __animals
```

Instead you define methods like this:

```
def __init__(Animal):
```

and define variables like:

```
Animal.__animals = []
```

which simply don't make sense.

Your problem is that you used a module (`Animal`) instead of `self`. I have no idea where you might have gotten this idea, but you may want to peruse [class definition in the Python documentation](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/classes.html).